# Problem with getting one item from json file through get method in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, filesystems

Basically I can get the whole list from json file but I cannot figure out how to get concrete item. When I use postman, path: http://localhost:3000/book/2 for example it returns bookcode does not exist

```
app.get('/book/list', (req, res) => {
  const books = getBookData()
  res.send(books)
})

app.get("/book/:code", (req, res) => {
  const code = req.params.code
  const existsBook = getBookData();
  const filterBook = existsBook.filter(book => book.code !== code)
  if (existsBook.length === filterBook.length) {
    return res.status(400).send({error: true, msg: 'bookcode does not exist'})
  }
})

const getBookData = () => {
  const jsonData = fs.readFileSync('books.json')
  return JSON.parse(jsonData.toString())
}
```

here is json file

```
[{"code":2,"name":"Name of the wind","author":"Patrrick Rothfuss"},{"code":3,"name":"Wise Man's Fear","author":"Patrrick Rothfuss"},{"code":4,"name":"The Doors of Stone","author":"Patrrick Rothfuss"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be because *req.query.code* is by default a string, not number. This tripped me up once.

A reliable solution would be to use parseInt.

```
const code = parseInt(req.params.code)
```

Not working? You could also try a traditional Number ()

```
const code = Number(req.params.code)
```

Comment: yes that works, but I forgot that I should put something in response and res.send(filterBook) returns the other books and not the one I want. Do you know the solution?

Comment: @TomášHejlík maybe swap out !== with == on your filter function.